# Is there a faster way to iterate through a MongoResultList in Grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and querying a list of entities from the database using:

```
List<Entity> entities = Entity.findAllByCode("code");
```

The query is quite fast and returns approximated 9000 rows. The issue is when I try to iterate over the list:

```
entites.each {
    // Do something in here
}
```

Iterating over the list (with nothing inside the loop) will take over 9 seconds.

From what I could find, this is due to GORM converting each element in the MongoResultList to a Entity object (from DBObjects).

Is there another way that I should be iterating over this list? Is there something I'm missing in the de/serialization process that I can change to increase performance?

UPDATE:

Here is the relevant portion of the MongoResultList class that is the main bottleneck. This gets called whenever I iterate over the list. The second time through, the iteration is orders of magnitude faster.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        if(initializedObjects.size() > index) {
            return initializedObjects.get(index);
        }
        else if(!initialized) {
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                if(internalIndex > index) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot retrieve element at index " + index + " for cursor size " + size());
                Object o = convertDBObject(cursor.next());
                initializedObjects.add(internalIndex,o);
                if(index == internalIndex++) {
                    return o;
                }
            }
            initialized = true;
        }
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot retrieve element at index " + index + " for cursor size " + size());
    }
```

It's the `convertDBObject()` method call that is consuming the time. The cause is the deserialization, but are their any better alternatives?

Comment: Do you need `Entity` objects? What are you planning to do in the loop?

Comment: The entity contains numbers (financial data) that I need to analyze and dump to the screen. I could utilize the raw DBObjects, if that would be faster, though I was hoping for a more Grails-like or GORM-like solution.

Comment: Hm. Maybe a problem with lazy loading of result sets. Is `code` indexed?

Comment: Yes, `code` is indexed. It is lazy loading, but I don't think it's querying the database. I think it's lazy-deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

If creating the `Entity` instances is the bottle neck, you can try retrieving just the properties you need:

```
def rows = Entity.withCriteria {
    eq('code', code)

    projections {
        property('a')
        property('b')
        property('c')
    }
}
```

The criteria query shown above would return a `List` like this:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]
```

If you need more info on projections, I have an [article](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-select-clause/) for that.

Comment: This is good, however, in my particular case, my `Entity` class only has 7 fields and I need all of them for the business logic. This is a fantastic approach for some of our larger collections to limit our focus.